# Accessing Cookie From A Sub Domain In Firefox/Safari Fails

Tags: firefox, cookies, safari, third-party-cookies

It looks like this question has been asked many time on SO but my findings are contradicting with what is explained elsewhere (or may be I am missing something).

---

***PROBLEM***

Firefox and Safari no longer support third party cookies, which means -

- cookies added by **example1.com** will be visible on host **example1.com** (first party cookies)
- cookies added by **example2.com** will not be visible on host **example1.com** (third party cookies)

---

***FIRST APPROACH***

To solve this issue, I tried following -

- Used a subdomain from **example1.com** as **subdomain.example1.com**
- Pointed it to **example2.com**
- Dropped cookies on **example1.com** using **subdomain.example1.com**

---

***FINDINGS***

- Chrome continues to show cookies from **subdomain.example1.com** in **example1.com**
- Firefox / Safari do not show cookies from **subdomain.example1.com** in **example1.com**

---

***SECOND APPROACH***

In this case I did opposite to approach 1 -

- Used a subdomain from **example1.com** as **subdomain.example1.com**
- Pointed it to **example2.com**
- Dropped cookies on **subdomain.example1.com** using **example1.com**

Please note that the host website in this case is running on **subdomain.example1.com**

---

***FINDINGS***

All browsers in this case started displaying the cookies.

---

***QUESTIONS***

- Why can't I add cookies on host **example1.com** from **subdomain.example1.com** in case of Firefox / Safari?
- Adding cookies on host **subdomain.example1.com** from **example1.com** works fine but is that a practically acceptable approach? (host website should never be a subdomain I mean)

Please let me know if you need more information.

Thanks